# How to get a tr value within a filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I having issues grabbing my data within a jquery filter. I have tried finding a solution but haven't been able to find one. I am fairly new with Jquery so I believe this might be a trivial answer.

I like to loop through my array checking it against the cells value, How do I fetch the cells current value / (this) value?

EDIT: Thanks for the help, final solution as follows. Where datesToSearchFor is an array of string dates and nth-child(2) is my dates column in my table.

```
  $("#UnfinishedTable tr").filter(function () {
    if (this.id !== 'headerRow') {
        var isItThere = false;
        var data = $(this).find("td:nth-child(2)").html();//my dates column
        datesToSearchFor.forEach(function (entry) {
            if (data == entry) {against are array of dates
                isItThere = true;
            }
        });
    }
    if (isItThere) {//if one was found show the row else hide it
        $(this).show()
    }
    else {
        if (this.id !== 'headerRow') {
            $(this).hide()
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: TR does not have values, the TDs (cells) have value. So firstly you need to loop through each cell of each row. Secondly .text() is how you read the text value of an element or .html() to read the whole html inside an element. Thirdly the "this" is not the same when you are inside the child loop because each loop has it's own "this"

Comment: good point. I was grabbing this in the wrong scope. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#unfinishedTable tr').not('#headerRow').each(function(){
    var val = $(this).attr('value');
    var src = datesToSearchFor.find(function(n){return n == val;});   
    $(this).css({'display' : src == null ? 'none' : ''});
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the .find solution.

Answer (score 1):

Filtering is for finding your elements, not acting upon them.  After you `.filter()`, you should put your logic into `.each()`

```
$('#UnfinishedTable tr')
  .not('#headerRow')
  .each(function () {
    ... // logic
    $(this).show();
  });
```

The above example uses `.not()` as that is closer to what your desired logic is.

Answer (score -1):

The above code seems to be correct, does the console return any errors? Is datesToSearchFor a string vector? Is headerRow the id you assigned to the header tr to ignore it?

Comment: id is undefined, datesToSearchFor is an array of string Dates and header row is the ID for the first row where my headers are to be ignored.